# Bibliography formatting issue

Tags: bibliographies

I am working on a template of a journal with Natbib package. they have added a .bst file too. While entering the Bibliography using \bibliography, some of the references are split in two pages (i'e 1/2 lines are coming to next page). hoe to put thme together in one page

[image: Screenshot 2023-07-20 020700]

As I am using command there is no place to manupulate the space. I guess little change in .bst file might help

Comment: maybe this can help: https://ctan.org/pkg/nowidow

Comment: Sorry, but none of these helped me.

Comment: \usepackage{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{2pt}
\setlength{\bibhang}{1.27cm}
These are the template command.
I have tried to remove the %setlength command.It works fine but he lines spaces increases, which looks odd